# Creating matrix in R, is there a faster way?

Tags: r, matrix

So basically, here is the matrix I need to create

```
sig = matrix(c(0.56^2, 0.56*7.77*-0.07, 0.56*13.48*-0.095, 0.56*16.64*-0.095,
               0.56*7.77*-0.07, 7.77^2, 7.77*13.48*0.959, 7.77*16.64*0.936,
               0.56*13.48*-0.095, 7.77*13.48*0.959, 13.48^2, 13.48*16.64*0.997,
               0.56*16.64*-0.095, 7.77*16.64*0.936, 13.48*16.64*0.997, 16.64^2), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
```

I am writing to ask if there is some better way to figure out the matrix without actually entering every value? It is very easy to make mistakes, I suppose.

Comment: There probably is, but it's hard to say unless we know what the pattern in the matrix entries are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a covariance matrix so define the standard deviations, `d`, and define the correlations (in the upper triangular portion of the correlation matrix), `cors`, and reconstruct `sig` from those two.

Given `d` and `cors` we define `m` to be a diagonal matrix with 1/2 in each diagonal element. Then in the next line insert the correlations into its upper triangular part. In the following line we fill in the lower triangular part by adding `t(m)` which also sets the diagonal elements to 1 (1/2 + 1/2 = 1) giving the correlation matrix `corr`.  Finally convert `corr` to a covariance matrix by multiplying by `outer`.

```
d <- c(0.56, 7.77, 13.48, 16.64)
cors <- c(-0.07, -0.095, 0.959, -0.095, 0.936, 0.997)

m <- diag(length(d))/2
m[upper.tri(m)] <- cors
corr <- m + t(m)
sig2 <- corr * outer(d, d)

all.equal(sig, sig2)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Other direction

Note that to go in the other direction, i.e. derive `d` and `cors` from `sig`, that the standard deviations and correlations are respectively:

```
d2 <- sqrt(diag(sig))
all.equal(d, d2)
## [1] TRUE

cors2 <- cov2cor(sig)[upper.tri(sig)]
all.equal(cors, cors2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds... +1

Comment: can i kindly know why for command ```(m + t(m))``` works and why we don't need to type diagonal line 1. I have difficulty of understanding ```m <- diag(length(d))/2
m[upper.tri(m)] <- c(-0.07, -0.095, 0.959, -0.095, 0.936, 0.997)``` these two lines

Comment: Have added some commentary.